# Parse a keystore file and get values of "Alias name" & "Expiry date"

Tags: linux, shell, awk, sed, keytool

I want to parse a keystore file and get only the value of  "Alias name:" and expiry date that comes next to "until:" . Anything with awk / sed will work.

Tried the below 2 commands that gives the value. But I want it in a single command

```
line=`keytool -list -v -keystore nonprod_truststore.jks | grep -e "Alias name" | awk -F'Alias name:' '{print $2}'`


line2=`keytool -list -v -keystore nonprod_truststore.jks | grep -e "until:" | awk -F'until:' '{print $2}'`
```

### **Sample Input keystore file content:**

```
Alias name: Vaerikeysamplename004
Creation date: Mar 25, 2004
Entry type: trustedCertEntry

Owner: OU=VeriSign Trust Network, OU="(c) 1998 VeriSign, Inc. - For authorized use only", OU=Class 1 Public Primary Certification Authority - G2, O="VeriSign, Inc.", C=US
Issuer: OU=VeriSign Trust Network, OU="(c) 1998 VeriSign, Inc. - For authorized use only", OU=Class 1 Public Primary Certification Authority - G2, O="VeriSign, Inc.", C=US
Serial number: 1234jeyjfffdfd
Valid from: Sun May 17 20:00:00 EDT 1998 until: Tue Aug 01 19:59:59 EDT 2028
Certificate fingerprints:
         MD5:  DB:23:3D:F9:99:FA:4B:33:95:ee:44:73:5E:7D:41:83
         SHA1: 27:3E:ss:24:57:FD:C4:F9:0C:55:E8:2B:56:16:ff:62:F5:32:E5:47
         SHA256: 34:1D:E9:8B:13::6E:C6:5B:9A:51:CE:6E:D0:67:D0:0E:C7:CE:9B:7F
Signature algorithm name: RSASHASAM
Subject Public Key Algorithm: 1024-bit RSA key
Version: 1
```

### **Expected output**

```
Vaerikeysamplename004 Tue Aug 01 19:59:59 EDT 2028
```

Comment: `awk` can do multiple "greps" in one pass. `awk -F: '/until:/{...} ; /Alias name:/{...}' file`. You'll have to experiment with the `$2` etc to get the results you want. (I don't have a keystore file to experiment with, you might want to add a sample one to your question). Good luck.

Comment: `keytool ... | awk -F: '/^Alias name/{print $2} ; /until:/{sub(/.*until:/,"");print}'` should be close. Good luck

Answer (score 5):

Using any awk:

```
$ awk 'sub(/^Alias name: /,""){name=$0} sub(/.*until: /,""){print name, $0}' file
Vaerikeysamplename004 Tue Aug 01 19:59:59 EDT 2028
```

Answer (score 3):

With your shown samples please try following GNU `awk`.
Written and tested in GNU `awk` using its `RS` and `RT` capability.

```
awk -v RS='Alias name: [^\n]*|Valid from: [^\n]*' '
RT && num=split(RT,arr,": "){
  val=(val?val OFS :"") arr[num]
}
END{
  if(val){
   print val
  }
}
'  Input_file
```

Answer (score 2):

```
$ awk -F': ' '$1=="Alias name" {a=$2} / until: / {print a,$NF}' file 
Vaerikeysamplename004 Tue Aug 01 19:59:59 EDT 2028
```

We use `:`  (colon-space) as field separator. When the first field is `Alias name` we store the second in variable `a`. When a line matches space-`until`-colon-space we print variable `a` and the last field.

Answer (score 1):

This might work for you (GNU sed):

```
sed '/Alias name: /h;/until: /H;$!d;x;s/.*: //mg;y/\n/ /' file
```

Make a copy of a line containing `Alias name:`  and append another line to it containing `until:` .

Delete all lines except the last, then swap to the copies and remove unwanted text and print the result.

N.B. The `m` flag on the  substitution command allows for multi-line input.

Answer (score 0):

... and the name of that one command is [`openssl`](https://www.openssl.org/docs/man3.1/man1/openssl-x509.html).

The good news is that with it you can tease out parts of
a certificate without reaching for `awk` and company: you
choose to rely on the `openssl` maintainers to insulate your
code from certificate-related-standard evolution and spare
yourself the trouble of handcrafting and maintaining queries
for *human-readable* fields.  The `keytool` command can export
its certificates in PEM format (base64) for `openssl` to
consume.

The bad news is that the `openssl x509` command processes
a certificate at a time *not* in bulk. (Handling of multiple
certificates seems not so common to merit support.)

So, suppose there is a `lib/security/cacerts` `Java` keystore
file (its location is known to `keytool`), and there is a need
to print out the expiration date for every entry stored in
it:

```bash
## (DEFAULT PASSWORD: changeit)
## Export all cacerts certificates in base64 format (RFC 4648) and store
## them as cacerts.bundle:
cd /tmp
keytool -cacerts -list -rfc > cacerts.bundle

mkdir pems && cd pems

## Undo the bundle file into separate PEM files (with header and footer).
## (This is ugly and may require more massageing.)
csplit ../cacerts.bundle -qz -f '' -b '%04d.pem~' \
  '%^Your keystore%2' \
  '/^\*\*\*\*\*\*/4' '{*}'

## Process each PEM file (with header and footer):
for f in *.pem~
do
  read a b alias_name < "$f"
  ex=$(openssl x509 -noout -enddate < "$f")

  ## 'not{Before,After}' are part of X.509 syntax (§4.1, RFC 5280), whereas
  ## 'Valid from:' and 'until:' are the `-v` output details.
  printf '%s %s\n' "$alias_name" "${ex#notAfter=}"
done
```

Now, usually, you would like to discover the expiration date
for a known alias (certificate), and you can try a pipeline
such as (the `eval` tomfoolery is for exposition only):

```bash
alias=debian:go_daddy_root_certificate_authority_-_g2.pem

## Look for $alias in the cacerts keystore:
exporter="keytool -cacerts -exportcert -rfc -alias \$alias"

## Report the expiration date:
parser='openssl x509 -noout -enddate'

## (DEFAULT PASSWORD: changeit)
## Run the query:
ex=$(eval echo "\$($exporter | $parser)")

printf '%s %s\n' "$alias" "${ex#notAfter=}"
```